# f:param to composite components

Tags: jsf-2, parameter-passing, facelets, composite-component

In JSF2.1 composite component if we try to pass f:param to a composite component (command button) and recieve in the component as editableValueHolder ,It doesn't seems to be working,

Any ideas?

```
 <mycomp id="button" outcome="newpage" >
    <f:param name="foo" outcome="bar" for="button"/>
  </mycomp>


 compositeComponent....
  <cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="action" targets="commandLink" required="true" />       
  </cc:interface>
  <cc:implementation>
    <h:commandLink id="commandLink"  action="#{cc.attrs.action}">

    </h:commandLink>
  </cc:implementation>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`<cc:insertChildren>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/composite/insertChildren.html).

```
<h:commandLink ...>
    <cc:insertChildren />
</h:commandLink>
```