# How to pass f:param to multiple h:link in composite?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, composite-component

I want to build a simple paginator component using GET link support and we can pass `f:param` to a composite using `cc:insertChildren`. [see answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10884447/fparam-to-composite-components)

The problem is i have multiple `h:link` which should all receive the params. But only the first one receives it in Mojarra. Even the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/cc/insertChildren.html) says its possible but may create duplicate id's which is not relevant with `f:param`

Rendering a facet is not working. Anyone knows why?

**Site**

```
<comp:paginator>
    <f:param name="category" value="#{bean.category}/>
</comp:paginator>
```

**Composite**

```
<h:link rel="prev">
    <cc:insertChildren/>
</h:link>

<h:link rel="next">
    <cc:insertChildren/>
</h:link>
```

Comment: Well it says 'The results are undefined if there are multiple occurrences of this element in the `<composite:implementation>` section'.

Comment: @EJP +1 for that. I would rather prefer duplicate id's then just ignoring it. Would easily solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems not to be possible so I can at least create something ugly like this:

```
<comp:paginator 
    param1Name="" param1Value="" param1Converter=""
    param2Name="" param2Value="" param2Converter=""
    param3Name="" param3Value="" param3Converter=""
    param4Name="" param4Value="" param4Converter=""
    param5Name="" param5Value="" param5Converter=""
/>
```